# Download multiple documents in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, download

We have disabled the `open with explorer` feature in document library's ribbon.Now customer wants to download multiple documents in one time.How to achieve this feature? 
Is this possible through any custom action or with the help of any custom coding?

Comment: Are you fine in having an app which does that job for you?

Comment: Am using SP 2013 on-premises Farm solution.Have not configured our env. to use the App Model development.Would like to know,how to achieve,if its not enabled in our environment.

Comment: This can be helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179923.aspx for your query.

Comment: At this point of time, this app model env.set up is too much for me.Is there any free solutions available- community wsp- kind of?I searched, but unable to find the same.

Comment: This is a feature developed for 2010 version, but you can give it a go for 2013 as well. http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2010/05/08/sharepoint-2010-download-as-zip-file-custom-ribbon-action.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i tried the same, just now.But unfortunately, the custom action created in the solution is not visible in the ribbon of my doc.lib in my SP 2013 site collection.

Comment: I enabled the devianpoint.downlaodzip feature on the site collection scope.But still the custom action DownloadAsZip is not enabled-its greyed out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25139/discussion-between-samolpp-p-and-asad-refai).

Answer (score 0):

How about drag/dropping files into the document Library (opened in an HTML5 browser) from the Windows Explorer?
Or mapping the network drive from the Newtork node in the Windows Explorer?

Comment: I have already disabled this feature through PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have prepared your environment to use SharePoint Apps, you can use the free [Download Multiple Documents](https://store.office.com/download-multiple-documents-WA104146066.aspx) app from the store.

Comment: I don't have that environment.we are using  Farm solution set up.